# An example of non trivial projections in a group von Neumann algebra

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ and $\text{vN}(G)$ be a torsion free group and its group von Neumann algebra. Is there a characterization of non trivial projections in $\text{vN}(G)$? If not, is a certain class of them studied?

Comment: A characterization in which terms? The definition itself is a characterization.

Comment: @YCor As functions on $G$, what we can say about projections; for example, in $\ell^\infty(G)$, the projection are in form $\chi_S$, where $S$ is a subset of $G$.

Comment: @YCor I want to know that for a given symmetric subset  $S$ of $G$ containing $e_G$, if there is a projection $P$ with support $S$? In other words, what form do  the support of a projection in the group von Neumann algebra have?

Comment: @Meisam Soleimani Malekan: I believe your question is asking too much. Note that if the group has the property that only the identity has a finite conjugacy class (and every other group element has an infinite conjugacy class), then the group von Neumann algebra contains no finite rank operators.